# Nodejs - Not showing list of array in ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I gotta a basic list app, when the user input some dog name and breed. And then add to a array and show to the user in the ejs file. No DB. But, I did this code first time on my pc watching a video lesson and then I tried to do myself on my note. I get it. IS THE SAME CODE! But on the PC works, and in the notebook don't.

In the picture is my main node file, and  bellow is my ejs code in a file called "index".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Doggy List</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/create_dog" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Dog name:">
    <input type="text" name="breed" placeholder="Dog breed:">
    <input type="submit" value="New Dog">

    </form>


    <% for(var i = 0; i < myDog.lenght; i++) { %>

        <li>The dog name is <strong> <%= myDog[i].name %> </strong> and the breed is: <strong> <%= myDog[i].breed %> </strong></li>

    <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

All elements shows in the screen. The forms etc...

Just the list is not showing.[my app.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTlK8.png)

Comment: You have `.lenght` instead of `.length`

Comment: Damnnnnn, such a minimalist detail. Thank you, brah.